how to set up refresh only for new dates of report in power report server
There are some reports on the Power bi report server. These reports have different sizes. Each report is connected to the auto refresh and each report has its own refresh time. However, 3 of these reports give errors during auto refresh like Memory error and do not refresh, therefore old data appears in the visuals. .
I want to give an example of a report. In this report, the dataset consists of SQL view and excel tables and measures. The view between the tables in the dataset has a large volume. All the columns in the view are necessary for the report. Most of the time,tehere is problem in sql views refrehsed.There is not problem in excel tabes.
As it is known, power auto refresh deletes and rewrites all the data in the table in the dataset. This takes a lot of memory and causes a memory error during the refresh. How can you refresh only the data on sysdate-1 during the refresh? keep it as it is, don't refresh it.
When I get such an error, I edit the report and manually refresh all the tables in it. After doing this, I save the report again. But it takes too much time and it no longer works.
i think Power BI Desktop incremental table update from Power Query. this link is different from my situation.İn there have problem for excel tables .But in my stiuation i have problem with sql view tables refresh in power bi
